# A good tool set for ASP.NET development

Tags: tools, asp.net

What are some good (or must have) ASP.NET development/debugging tools in addition to Visual Studio IDE?

So far the only trick in my pocket is .NET Reflector, that has come in handy before.

(I would limit browsers add-ons to IE if possible, since I'm working on a corporate intranet and using FF is not always an option).

Comment: It's a shame that Firefox is not always an option since Firebug is what I'd consider my most vital tool for ASP.NET development! But I was looking at IE9's built-in dev tools this morning, and it certainly looks like they've made some good steps forward (or, less charitably, it looks like they've taken a good shot at cloning Firebug!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing really missing is a http debugger. Perhaps the best option would be something like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as it plays with any and all browsers, or even without a browser if need be.

Answer (score 3):

At risk of incurring the holy war tag, I'd say productivity tools are always a nice boost.  Things like:

- GhostDoc: http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx
- Resharper / CodeRush: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ or http://www.devexpress.com/coderush

Also, I'd browse through the Extension Manager (Tools menu) in VS.  There's a lot of nice tools in there, but they're probably going to be applicable on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1):

- Something that integrates source control with VS
- NuGet NUnit and Visual NUnit (Extention Manager) or some other testing framework
- PowerCommands and Productivity PowerTools (Extention Manager)

Answer (score 0):

We use Telerik JustCode (http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) for code analysis, refactoring etc.

We work with JustCode because we're already using the Teleirk components so it was a natural fit, but we've found that using some form of analysis and refactoring tool like this (or like ReSharper or CodeRush, which have already been mentioned) is a significant development boost and well worth the investment.